# How to make multi options search query?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a full search query that contains a multiple options , the query might contain a `None` values depending on the user , so lets say i am looking for a service that provided by another user so i might be doing like this form:

Service by title

Service by username

Service by price (minimum, maximum)

Service type (discount, free)

which by that i can search using one of the above options .

Here is my query:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if search_form.validate_on_submit():
        service = search_form.service_name.data
        master = search_form.master_name.data
        start_price = str(search_form.min_price.data)
        finish_price = str(search_form.max_price.data)

        fullname = master.split()

        results = Service.query.join(Abonent, Abonent.id == Service.user_id).filter(Service.title.ilike("{}%".format(service))).filter(Abonent.name.ilike("{}%".format(fullname[0]))).filter(Abonent.price.between(start_price, finish_price)).all()
```

Now if i searched by **Service title** i got nothing, also for the rests , but if i searched by **Price** i got no results , please , any help making that work ???

Comment: Any suggestions guys ?!!

Comment: Please guys any help would be really appreciated , i am a junior web development and i need this to be done with my project that i am making !!

Comment: any answers guys !!